# Matlab string search and index

Tags: string, matlab, text, indexing

I have two text files:

```
stoplist = importdata('stoplist.txt');
vocab = importdata('vocabulary.txt');
```

I'm trying to create a vector where each element is the row number in `vocab` for each word in `stoplist` (It's guaranteed that `vocab` contains all words in `stoplist` plus many more). How does this work?

I don't really have any experience with strings in Matlab so I'm getting a bunch of errors about cells with everything I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[~, posVocab, posStoplist] = intersect(vocab, stoplist);`
And then decide how to sort those lists of positions.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html
You should also check example "Cell Array of Character Vectors with Trailing White Space" in the reference - trailing spaces mean strings are different.